# Convert *mut c_void to HWND

Tags: rust, windows-rs

I'm trying to convert a *mut c_void to HWND (https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/Foundation/struct.HWND.html) but it keeps throwing this error:

```
mismatched types
  expected struct `HWND`
found raw pointer `*mut c_void`
```

How can I safely convert a *mut c_void to HWND (since HWND is built out of a c_void).

```
let hwnd = match parent.handle {
  RawWindowHandle::Win32(_handle) => _handle.hwnd,
  _ => panic!()
};


let mut test: windows::Win32::Foundation::HWND = hwnd;
```

I want an HWND from hwnd, but it throws this error:

> mismatched types
> expected struct `HWND`
> found raw pointer `*mut c_void`

Thank you.

Comment: and where does come from this handle ? windows crate is the official windows bind of microsoft. So the crate you use to get this handle should use windows type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast your pointer to isize and then construct HWND:

```rust
fn ptr_to_hwnd(ptr: *mut c_void) -> HWND {
    HWND(ptr as _) // struct HWND(pub isize)
}
```

I'd just [`transmute`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/mem/fn.transmute.html) though

Comment: Why use unsafe code when you can avoid it? Using `transmute()` is a bad idea.

Comment: Yup. If at all possible, always prefer to avoid unsafe. Unsafe really is for cases there's no other option. It's just good design. There's less invariants to keep track of that way.